# Designing media and lesson tables for two 1:n relationships

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relationship

I am designing a database with three tables.

Its Media table which in some type of media, has n lesson (1:n relation).

Every lesson has some media (1:n relation).

Is this a correct design? Is there is another solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: What is a reference to the *design method* are you following? If you are not following one, how do you expect to accomplish anything?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have ID in both of them?

[Media] -> Id, LessonId, Name, ...

[Lesson] -> Id, Name, ...

You can get the media from the lesson via a join query.

Comment: both table has relation to each other. I have to.

Comment: I can't get the reason why you must have a double relation.. but  I would make a table between, like [MediaLesson] -> MediaId, LessonId

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Learn about design. Read a textbook. Work to a particular design method. This design suggests you still need to learn basics.

It is unlikely that your design is appropriate. We can't tell because you are not telling us enough. In your design a media (maybe) "has a" lesson (whatever you mean by that) and a lesson (maybe) "has a" media (whatever you mean by that). The rest of your message suggests you probably want a table about media, a table about lessons and a table about some application relationship/association that you have not explained but called "has a". Your use of nullable FKs referencing the other table is probably not appropriate, but what is appropriate depends on what your tables mean.

What is the application criterion by which a row goes into either of those tables? You need to *first* identify the application relationships you are interested in, and for each one pin down its characterizing *predicate*--fill-in-the-(named-)blanks statement template parameterized by column names--that a row makes into a true statement when in its table.

The straightforwared design might be (if each Media, Lesson & Type has one name):

```
Media(mname,tname) -- media MNAME is of type TNAME
    PK(mname)
Lesson(lname) -- lesson LNAME exists
    PK (lname)
Whatever(lname, mname) -- blah lesson LNAME blah blah media MNAME blah
    PK (lname, mname)
    FK (lname) references Lesson
    FK (mname) references Media
```

If you want ids (why?):

```
Media(mid, name, tid)
    PK (mid)
    FK (tid) references Type
Type(tid, name)
    PK(tid)
Lesson(lid, name)
    PK(lid)
Whatever(mid,lid)
    FK (lid) references Lesson
    FK (mid) references Media
```

ER design methods would call Media, Lesson and Type entity tables and Whatever a relationship or association table.

"Cardinality" means different things and is described differently in different design methods. Which one are you using?

More generally, you need to tell us what constraints must hold for the table values to make sense given the application. A FK constraint says values in a list of columns in a table must also appear a certain other place. If an lid and mid participate in Whatever, might that lid particpate with another mid? Vice versa? Does every lid/mid in Lesson/Media have to appear in Whatever? The constaints *follow* from the chosen predicates and what application situations can arise.

If certain constraints hold, you might want to rearrange your tables to record the same information but make it easier to force them to hold, or to make the new design's constraints simpler, and/or to make the new design's tables simpler.